# "squeamish" and "relishing in"

Tags: meaning

"It  looks at the somewhat squeamish work being produced by artists relishing in new gene technologies."

1. What type of artworks are "squeamish works"?
2. What does "relishing in" mean here? Does it mean "the artists working in the field of ..."?

Comment: You haven’t given much context to go on but I assume these are ‘artists” who are creating/designing new living things by manipulating genes.  This kind of work could be considered squeamish by some.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "Squeamish" is perfectly acceptable here. It's a rhetorical device called "hypallage" in Greek and "transferred epithet" in English. It's the transfer of an adjective (often one that describes a feeling), to a noun other than the person or thing it is actually describing. In this case, we assume the viewer would be squeamish, but the adjective has been transferred to the work.

It's a common device, often used in poetry, as in two of these examples from *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage)*

> "On the idle hill of summer/Sleepy with the flow of streams/Far I
>   hear..." (A.E. Housman, A Shropshire Lad) — idle hill... sleepy is a
>   hypallage: it is the narrator, not the hill, who exhibits these
>   features.
>
> "Fitting the clumsy helmets just in time" — Wilfred Owen, "Dulce et Decorum est"
>
> "restless night" — The night was not restless, but the person who was awake through it was.
>
> "happy morning" — Mornings have no feelings, but the people who are awake through them do.

There are more examples at *[Grammar About.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/transferredepitheterm.htm)*

Comment: Why should we assume that the viewer rather than the artist is the true referent? Before chasly gave the reference, I was assessing that 'artist' was only associated with art with 30% probability.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been written by someone who does not understand the words 'squeamish' or 'relishing'.

1. I suspect that the author has confused 'squeamish' with 'to squirm' and such artworks therefore make one squirm.
2. Here the author has incorrectly compounded two idioms:

   (a) produced by artists relishing new gene technologies

   (b) produced by artists delighting in new gene technologies

This is from Art and Science By Sîan Ede.
Note that the text has other errors.

Comment: The context is absolutely essential here. Thank you.

Comment: I took a quick "look inside" the book on Amazon. It's well-written.

Answer (score 0):

"Chapter 7, 'New Bodies for Old,' shows how traditional attitudes to the body as God’s marvellous machine have altered as the world has become secularised. *It also looks at the somewhat squeamish work being produced by artists relishing in new gene technologies*.”

The OP refers to a quotation from *Art and Science* by Siân Ede (2005 I. B. Tauris & Co Ltd). My, admittedly cursory, survey of the book indicates that the author is erudite and highly articulate. I find it unlikely that Siân Ede was employing language she was unfamiliar with or ignorant of.

“**squeamish work**” can be understood in context as artwork concerned with topics that, though “*traditional attitudes*” have “*altered as the world has become secularised*,” are still approached with a degree of caution and nervousness by those (whether artist or audience) in whom some semblance of the traditional, religious sensibilities yet linger.

And yet, the artists who are producing these non-traditional, avant-garde works are “**relishing in**,” that is, deriving enjoyment from or taking delight in, the “*new gene technologies*,” and (presumably) the expanded horizons these afford the artist.

> [**squeamish**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squeamish) *adjective*: afraid to deal with or do things that might hurt or offend people; having an unpleasantly nervous or doubtful feeling. (Merriam-Webster *online*)
>
> [**relish**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relishing) *noun*: 3 a: enjoyment of or delight in something that satisfies one's tastes, inclinations, or desires. (Merriam-Webster *online*)